# TikZ: pgfmath operation doesn't give the expected result

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

In this MWE, it is expected to get seven circles equally spaced in the angular direction with stretching radius. However, I got this weird output.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0,1,...,6}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ml{1.2^(\i-1)}
        \draw (1,1)++(\x*30:5*\ml) circle[radius=1];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` which discards everything after the decimal point.  The first four powers of 1.2 lie between 1 and 2 so truncate to 1.  The next three lie between 2 and 3 so truncate to 2.  To fix this, replace `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` with `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362136/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0,1,...,6}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ml{1.2^(\i-1)}
  %\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ml{1.2^(\i-1)}
        \draw (1,1) ++(\x*30:5*\ml) circle[radius=1];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(I added lines to the circles in the picture to show the radii more explicitly.)

[image: Expanding radii]

Comment: Many thanks, I followed [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324743/2288), but it seems I didn't pay enough attention to this matter.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou In that answer the use of `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` is to ensure that what goes at the end of the `\foreach` loop is definitely an integer (and not even, say, 2.0).  This is a common habit that some of us have gotten into because it avoids an occasional issue with the `\foreach` loop.

Comment: I see, I appreciate your willingness to explain it to me. Many Thanks.